# How to stop having to press enter in drop down menus?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, winrar, right-click

I used a different PC the other day and noticed that for example in order to extract a file in Windows 7  using WinRAR I needed to only press <kbd>right click</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, as opposed to <kbd>right click</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> when using my computer.

How can I make my computer behave the same way?

Comment: Assuming it has nothing to do with you both having the same version, you could try AutoHotKey to map this

Comment: Nah it has nothing to do with the version, it worked like this for every drop down menu choice. And that PC did not have AutoHotKey installed.

Comment: When you press `Enter`, what exactly is `Enter` doing at that point? Saying yes to some kind of dialog box?

Comment: So you don't want a work around, your question is how to make your PC behave in the *exact* same way?

Comment: @Dave exactly. Enter chooses the selected menu in the drop down menu.

Comment: @misha256 Enter chooses the selected menu in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have two or more items on the menu that use the letter `E` as the keyboard shortcut, so that when you press <kbd>E</kbd> it is not sure which menu item you want.

The other PC had only one item on the menu with `E` so there is no question which menu item to use.

What you can do to eliminate the other menu item(s) depends on exactly what this menu is, which is not clear from the question as asked.